# Trouble specifying destination filename for use in FileInfo.Copy example from MSDN

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I'm using two DateTimePickers to specify a date range, then I'm using a CheckedListBox to specify some strings for filenames with wildcards to enumerate in each day's subdirectory contained within a system environment variable path. I want to copy from that source to a destination using FileInfo.Copy.

I have my code already creating the necessary directories. But I'm having trouble specifying the destination filenames -- they are not being specified at all with how I have this written.

I was thinking of using regular expressions, but after some digging I found [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that seems to do what I want already. I think I need to alter my code in order to use it. I could use some assistance fitting what I already have into what MSDN shows in its example.

I have been on this part of my program for a month now, which has led me to learn quite a bit about c#, parallel programming, async, lambda expressions, background workers, etc. What seems should be simple has become a big rabbit hole for me. For this question I just need a nudge in the right direction, and I will greatly appreciate it!

Here is my code as it stands:

```
    private async void ProcessFiles()
    {

        // create a list of topics
        var topics = topicsBox.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();

        // create a list of source directories based on date range
        var directories = new List<string>();
        var folders = new List<string>();
        for (DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
            date.Date <= dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
            date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            directories.Add(_tracePath + @"\" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"\");
            folders.Add(@"\" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"\");
        }

        // create a list of source files to copy and destination
        // revise based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
        foreach (var path in directories)
        {
            var path1 = path;
            try
            {
                foreach (var files2 in folders)
                {
                    // create the target directory
                    var destPath = textBox1.Text + @"\" + textBox4.Text + files2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Target directory is {0}", destPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Destination filename is {0}", files2);
                    foreach (var files in topics)
                    {
                        foreach (string sourcePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path1, files + "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        {
                            // copy the files to the temp folder asynchronously
                            Console.WriteLine("Copy {0} to {1}", sourcePath, destPath);
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePath.Replace(sourcePath, destPath));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Simplify my code" is NOT a valid and allowed type of question here.  You must ask specific technical questions only.  Try reading other peoples questions to see what is and is not allowed.

Comment: I will update the title.

Comment: @JK. will "Help, I'm stuck; I don't want to break what I have working now." suffice?

Comment: I just noticed in your comment you mentioned "copy .. asynchronously". Do you need to do it asynchronously? I'd suggest doing it synchronously first and making sure your logic is correct.

Comment: @Sam, I was hoping to do that after I get the destination filename with destination path working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `sourcePath` contains the source path and filename. You can easily construct the destination path from that, like so:

```
// Get just the filename of the source file.
var filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);

// Construct a full path to the destination by combining the destination path and the filename.
var fullDestPath = Path.Combine(destPath, filename);

// Ensure the destination directories exist. Don't pass in the filename to CreateDirectory!
Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
```

Then you can copy the file (synchronously) like this:

```
File.Copy(sourcePath, fullDestPath);
```

Comment: Right now, the destPath does not contain the filename. sourcePath has the entire path including the filename. I'm not sure how to pass that into destPath.

Comment: Sorry I should have looked at the code a little closer (when there's a lot of code to explain a seemingly simple problem, I (and I'm sure others) often read it a little too hastily!). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's okay.. It shows my lack of knowledge / experience, which is why I'm here asking for help! Thank you for looking it over..

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I needed. I'm still working on how to fit this into what I already have, but what I needed was Path.Combine() absolutely! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! If you find yourself manipulating path components by hand, definitely look at `System.IO.Path`. You'll probably find something to do what you need.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know this worked like a charm for me! I have the MSDN example incorporated in and it's working flawlessly. Thanks again!